# Test android application onn samsung galaxy grand

Tags: android-testing

I am using ubuntu 14.04 os and i have adt bundle for 64 bit. How can i test the android application which is created in these adt on samsung galaxy grand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

either use android emulator that google provides (as far as i know, that won't be an issue even if your OS is 64bit), or connect your device using adb and run it directly.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to test in windows.
I am using windows **7 ultimate + Android studio**.
**1**. Install Android studio
**2**. create hello world android app project.
**3**. click 'run' it should list your device to run app on.

**If it does not show in device** list follow below linkto first install Handset Manufacturer specific driver for andoid.
[download and install android driver for debugging](http://www.teamandroid.com/2013/03/11/samsung-galaxy-grand-usb-drivers-download/)